# How do I link to a downloadable file in CakePHP 3.6?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

How do I link to a downloadable file in CakePHP 3.6? The file is webroot/files/filename.pdf

I can create the link using

```
$this->Html->link('Link text', '/files/filename.pdf');
```

but when I click on it, I get the message "FilesController could not be found.".

I've searched the documentation and online, but can't find any mention of this.

Comment: Is the file really at /files/filename.pdf? The message indicates that the file could not be found and therefore the app tries to apply the standard controller/action fallback route it, just to discover that this controller does not exist either.

Comment: Thank you!  You were right - I had saved it with a different name on the fileserver!  Can't believe it was something so simple, but I'll leave this here in case it helps anyone else at a later stage.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to David, I realised I was doing the right things as far as Cake was concerned, but was using the wrong file name and linking to a file that didn't exist on the server.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the download attribute in your anchor tag. For cakephp 3, you can pass it something like

```
$this->Html->link('Link text', '/files/filename.pdf',['download'=>'filename.pdf']);
```

or

```
$this->Html->link('Link text', '/files/filename.pdf',array('download'=>'filename.pdf'));
```

Comment: Thank you!  That's helpful to know!